# Does #[derive(PartialEq, Eq)] increase code size?

Tags: rust, size, traits, equality

I submitted a [patch to `derive-builder`](https://github.com/colin-kiegel/rust-derive-builder/pull/257#issuecomment-1154413989) because I needed the ability to test failures generated. This patch enabled `Eq` and `PartialEq` so I could I test for failures using `assert_eq!()`.

The question asked was,

> My understanding is that generating unnecessary trait implementations can increase code size.

It is my understanding that implementations that are not used do not generate *more* code? Which of these two is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did to test this theory, I generated a simple binary,

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
  id: i64
}

fn main() {
  let a = Foo { id: 42 }; => Foo
  println!("Hello, world! [{} {:?}]", a.id, a);
}
```

I then did the same generation but with `#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]`. In this, I found both generated the same hash; they were identical. Not content, I also tried creating a library and compiling with `--release`. Same thing. This time with just `struct Foo` (no `main`). In this case, I did observe a difference, here is the nuance:

- Between the two runs the rlib (rust library) file had a different size.
- An `rlib` is an `ar`chive. For me it had three files, one of them ended in `cgu.0.rcgu.o` the other in `cgu.1.rcgu.o`, and there was one file that was `lib.rmeta`.
- Of the files in the archive, the `*.o` files were exactly the same (hashed).
- The `lib.rmeta` file was larger in the library that also derived `Eq`, and `PartialEq`.

Now as to the merit of [rmeta, the Rust documentation says this](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/backend/libs-and-metadata.html#rmeta),

> An rmeta file is custom binary format that contains the metadata for the crate. This file can be used for fast "checks" of a project by skipping all code generation (as is done with cargo check), collecting enough information for documentation (as is done with cargo doc), or for pipelining. This file is created if the --emit=metadata CLI option is used.
> **rmeta files do not support linking, since they do not contain compiled object files.**

So it seems *something* gets bigger, but that something is **ONLY** used for tooling purposes.

I tried the above test with the library with and without `pub`. I would expect if a function was generated that wasn't used it would have at the least resulted in one `.o` file being larger. I was not able to observe this though.

Comment: In a less technical but more interactive way, you can also play around with something like [this GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PMdx466zb) program, where you can see live updates of what gets optimized out. As Evan already described, even by having a `#[derive(...)]`, no extra code is generated unless it is used later, but seeing it in action may be more helpful/interesting for certain types of learners.

Comment: technically derive just produce a function, and a function not used don't generate bin code. But, if the function is marked as public from the crate, it will be compiled if the crate is compiled, because the compiler can't assume this function is not used outside this context. but if you download the crate, import it, uise the crate but not the derived trait, then it will not generate bin code.

Comment: @Bamontan that's not what I observe. From the above example, the two files used in linking (the `.o` files) do not have additional generated functions when deriving `Eq` and `PartialEq`

Comment: @EvanCarroll what happens if you have a more complex struct? E.g. one that contains a `String` in addition to the `i64`? I suspect that the compiler has decided that the derived methods should always be inlined, explaining why the corresponding code is added to `rmeta` rather than in an object file.